# export csv rows where duplicate values found in column

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file where I am trying to export rows into another csv file only where the values in the id column have duplicates.

I have the following csv file...

```
"id","blablah"
"valOne","valTwo"
"valOne","asdfdsa"
"valThree","valFour"
"valFive","valSix"
"valFive","qwreweq"
"valSeven","valEight"
```

I need the output csv file to look like the following...

```
"valOne","valTwo"
"valOne","asdfdsa"
"valFive","valSix"
"valFive","qwreweq"
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$inputCsv = Import-CSV './test.csv' -delimiter ","
#$output = @()
$inputCsv | Group-Object -prop id, blablah | Where-Object {$_.id -gt 1} |
    Select-Object
        #@{n='id';e={$_.Group[0].id}},
                  #@{n='blablah';e={$_.Group[0].blablah}}
    #Export-Csv 'C:\scripts\powershell\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
#Write-Host $output
#$output | Export-Csv 'C:\scripts\powershell\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

I've searched multiple how-to's but can't seem to find the write syntax. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group on the ID property and if there is more than 1 count in the group then expand those and export.

```
$inputCsv = Import-CSV './test.csv' -delimiter ","

$inputCsv |
    Group-Object -Property ID |
        Where-Object count -gt 1 |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty group |
                Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

output.csv will contain

```
"id","blablah"
"valOne","valTwo"
"valOne","asdfdsa"
"valFive","valSix"
"valFive","qwreweq"
```

Comment: Thank you! The `Select-Object -ExpandProperty group` was the magic I was missing.